# Oracle SQL Developer first-time user: no connection string

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I installed oracle SQL Developer, but I am not having any connection string to connect to database.

How can I connect first time?

Comment: SQL developer is just an "IDE", it doesn't come with a database.

Comment: You can use Oracle Express 18c as your database.  It is free and has most of the features you need for basic SQL functionality. - https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/xe.html

Answer (score 0):

SQL Developer is a desktop application. It serves as a client for working with an Oracle database.

But, it’s NOT a database, nor does it come with one.

And you’re going to need a database.

You have lots of options going forward. I've tried to detail all of them [here](https://medium.com/oracledevs/i-installed-oracle-sql-developer-now-what-71230b9c9303).

TL;DR version:

1. Oracle XE, free to use for any purpose (works just fine in Docker)
2. Our VirtualBox Appliance - very easy to get going, free to use for learning purposes
3. LiveSQL - a website you can use to learn Oracle, with nothing to install
4. And something my article doesn't address, [Always Free Oracle Autonomous Database Cloud Service](https://medium.com/@FranckPachot/the-oracle-cloud-free-tier-37c27f3b1e19).